# Excel: Get / Filter invalid dates in column

Tags: excel

Need to reimport the invalid dates in "General".

Below is only a part of over a million rows. Mixed with valid Date format and numeric dates in "General" data type.

Excel should only filter with data type "General" in a column. Can do it one by one but as said before records are more or less in 1m.

```
3/25/64
4/7/59
22231
22653
19636
16257
1/1/63
8/28/49
```

I have already solved this by importing it at a separate table then validating the dates using sql. Just wanted to know how to do it via excel.

UPDATE (Brent Hackers' sample):

I tried to modify Brent's example. but it copies the whole excel.

Script

`Public Sub CopyRows()
    Dim icol As Integer
    Dim irow As Integer
    icol = 0
    While ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Offset(0, icol) <> ""
        irow = 0
        While ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Offset(irow, icol) <> ""
            If Selection.NumberFormat = "General" Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AB1").Offset(irow, icol).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(irow, icol)
            irow = irow + 1
            End If
        Wend
        icol = icol + 1
    Wend
End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot to go on.

Could you use something like this?

```
Dim icol As Integer
Dim irow As Integer
icol = 0
While ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, icol) <> ""
    irow = 0
    While ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(irow, icol) <> ""
        If Selection.NumberFormat = "General" Then ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, icol).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        irow = irow + 1
    Wend
    icol = icol + 1
Wend
```

OK - After your edits to your question I came up with this

```
Public Sub moveBadDatesToNewSheet()
    Dim icol As Integer
    Dim irowSrc As Integer
    Dim irowTgt As Integer
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet

    Set srcWS = ActiveSheet
    icol = 0
    Sheets.Add
    Set tgtWS = ActiveSheet
    While srcWS.Range("A1").Offset(0, icol) <> ""
        irowSrc = 0
        irowTgt = 0
        While srcWS.Range("A1").Offset(irowSrc, icol) <> ""
            If InStr(1, srcWS.Range("A1").Offset(irowSrc, icol), "/") = 0 Then
                tgtWS.Range("A1").Offset(irowTgt, icol) = srcWS.Range("A1").Offset(irowSrc, icol)
                irowTgt = irowTgt + 1
            End If
            irowSrc = irowSrc + 1
        Wend
        icol = icol + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

That will take each non-formatted date and drop it into a new sheet.  Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Can't test it yet. Will have to do this using windows.

Comment: I Updated my question. I tried runnning your script and it just modifies the date format. I need to copy the ones with general format. Will accept the answer once I make copy rows correctly.

Comment: Ok, so you want to copy just the dates that appear correctly (as dates) to another sheet?

Comment: I want to copy the dates that is numeric or "General" data type to another sheet.